# Degrees of irreducible representations of an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero and $G$ a finite abelian group. If $K$ is algebraically closed, then every irreducible $K$-representation of $G$ has degree 1. If $K$ is not necessarily algebraically closed, are there any results on the degrees of the irreducible representations?

On page 306 of the book "Representation Theory of Finite Groups and Associative Algebras" by Curtis and Reiner a $K$-conjugate class is defined. Are the degrees of the irreducible representations in bijection with the cardinalities of the $K$-conjugate classes?

NOTE: The definition of $K$-conjugacy is as follows: Let $n$ be the exponent of $G$. Let $\mu_n$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity and $L=K(\mu_n)$. Let $H=\text{Gal}(L/K)$. Then we can identify $H$ with a subgroup of $H'$ of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. We say that 2 elements $a$ and $b$ in $G$ are $K$-conjugate if $xbx^{-1}=a^r$ for some $x \in G$ and some $r \in H'$

Comment: As I gave away my copy of C&R years ago can you include in your question the definition of $K$-conjugate class?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I just added the definition above

Comment: Thanks. I think that one can reduce your question to the case when $K$ is replaced by $K\cap \mathbb{Q}(\mu_n)$. Your first question would then be about how the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial factorises over $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_d)$ for $d\mid n$. I can't prove that the answer to your second question is "yes" but believe you're right.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it. Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero and $G$ a finite abelian group. Let $V$ be a simple $KG$-module with character $\psi$. Let $\bar{K}$ be an algebraic closure of $K$. Assume that $W$ is a simple $\bar{K}G$-submodule of $\bar{K}V:=\bar{K} \otimes_{K} V$ with character $\chi:=\chi_W$.

If $\text{Gal}(K(\chi)/K)=\{\sigma_1, \sigma_2,..., \sigma_d\}$, then
$$\psi=\text{m}_K(\chi)(\sigma_1(\chi)+\sigma_2(\chi)+\cdots+\sigma_d(\chi))$$
where $\text{m}_K(\chi)$ is the Schur index.

Since $\bar{K}$ is algebraically closed and $G$ is abelian, therefore $\chi(1)=\text{dim}_{\bar{K}}(W)=1$. Therefore we get $\psi(1)=\text{m}_K(\chi)[K(\chi):K]$. This answers the first question.

Comment: This is very close to answering Q2 as well, using $G\simeq\hat{G}$.